# in Netlogo, is there a way I can load a CSV file into a slider or a monitor box?

Tags: csv, simulation, netlogo, modeling

in Netlogo, is there a way I can load a CSV file into a slider or a monitor box?

I've already tried placing a csv file into a list that displays, but my group wants the data on the csv files into a slider, or a monitor box.

is that possible? can't find any tutorials.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive and specific about what you are trying to do? I don't understand what this even means.

Comment: Sliders and monitors deal with single values only. Presumably your CSV file has multiple values. Are they inputs for multiple values in a single run? Are they inputs for the same variable for multiple runs?

Answer (score 1):

You can create an "output" widget and display information there.

- http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/interface.html#interface
- http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dict/output-print.html

hth